# Dup-hammered questions should be editable only by relevant users?

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, abuse

This discussion have a reference to the following questions:

- [Test to see when a class attribute has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50641783/test-to-see-when-a-class-attribute-has-changed)
- [Test an element has changed status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643438/test-an-element-has-changed-status)

Both the questions was raised by the same OP bearing [`selenium`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) tag. I have dup-hammered the second question. Revisions below:

- [Revision 1 - Test to see when a class attribute has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50641783/1)
- [Revision 1 - Test an element has changed status](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50643438/1)

As a result the second question was ***marked** as duplicate* on `selenium` tag.

Now there had been a sudden edit to both the question and [`selenium`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) tag was completely replaced by [`selenium-webdriver`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) tag.

So now for you and the future readers/audience,

- None of the questions have the `selenium` tag.
- Second question is dup-hammered with a reference to the first question within `selenium` tag which have no reference now.

Now, unless the future readers/audience goes through the revision history, the will be a lot of *confusion* and *ambiguity* and perhaps none will have a clue what happened *under-the-hood*. Clearly both the questions are victims of abusive edits.

So can we implement a check point to restrict editing of dup-hammered questions only by relevant users?

Comment: What do you want us to do? If the edits are wrong, then roll them back (I'm not a expert in selenium or selenium-webdriver, so I can't judge). If the edits are fine, then I don't see the problem.

Comment: What would be the benefit? Our whole model is based on "edits by the community, for the community".... you want to change that to "edits by the community, for the community....... except for dup-hammered duplicates?".  But what if I'm another user stumbling on this question and I have some insight to make it better? I can't, because I'm not involved in the dup-hammer? Not to mention I can see potential for abuse with very low traffic tags where dupe-hammerers may be very low in number... If you have issues with these edits, you have the tools to change that. No need for a systems change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no abuse whatsoever going on here. Dupe hammering a question doesn't give you or your fellow gold badge holders any special authority over its content. [As BDL suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368915/dup-hammered-questions-should-be-editable-only-by-relevant-users#comment596629_368915), evaluate and deal with the tag edits in the same way you would handle any other edit.